# how do I run cmd files in wine as administrator?

Tags: ubuntu, cmd.exe, administrator, wine

I am trying to run the following script using wine 5.0.1 in ubuntu 18.04

https://github.com/kkkgo/KMS_VL_ALL/releases

I tried to run the script using the command

```
wine cmd.exe /C Activate.cmd
```

and

```
wineconsole Activate.cmd
```

Both return the error message:

```
==== ERROR ====
This script require administrator privileges.
To do so, right click on this script and select 'Run as administrator'
```

How can I run a cmd file as an administrator in wine?

Answer (score 3):

I Found a way!

1. run wine taskmgr to run the Task manager
2. Click "File" in the top left
3. Choose "New Task (Run)"
4. Choose "Browse" and Navigate to the directory where the file is located
5. Change File Types to All Files and choose the cmd file now
6. Click Open, Done!
   Hope i could help!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I run a cmd file as an administrator in wine?

It is not possible to elevate the process.  The elevation of a command prompt on Linux doesn’t mean anything.

The simplest thing, other than running this script under Windows like it was designed to do, is to do is remove the check entirely.

I would like to point out there is absolutely no legitimate use for this script.  **I would advise extreme caution.**

You simply need to remove the following line from the script.  **However, I have my doubts, it will complete successfully.**

`fsutil dirty query %SystemDrive% >nul 2>&1 || goto :E_Admin`